# how to restrict user from entering more than 10 numbers in react

Tags: reactjs

i tried this to restrict user from entering more than 10 numbers

```
  numberChangeHandler=(e)=>{
    const userInput={...this.state.userInput};
    if(userInput.number.length>=10)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
      userInput[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value
    }
    this.setState({userInput})
  }
```

but i wont be able to alter any changes once it reaches 10 digits .. cant use backspace as well.
Then i tried this:

```
  numberChangeHandler=(e)=>{
    const userInput={...this.state.userInput};
    if(userInput.number.length>10)
    {
      userInput[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value.replace("")
    }
    else{
      userInput[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value
    }
    this.setState({userInput})
  }
```

but this replaces my complete userInput to empty string once it reached 10 digits. can i get a solution please

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the number length

```
var x = 1234567;

x.toString().length;
```

Then if the variable is less than 10 you update the state, if its not you simply do nothing.

```
if(this.state.userInput.toString().length < 10 ){
this.setState({
    userInput: "The New User Input"
  })
}
```

Comment: but again i cant do any actions .. like not even use backspace after reaching 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

```
  numberChangeHandler=(e)=>{
    const userInput={...this.state.userInput};
    if(userInput.number.length>=10)
    {
      userInput[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value
      userInput.number=userInput.number.substr(0,10)
    }
    else{
      userInput[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value
    }
    this.setState({userInput})
  }
```

Comment: i solved it .. but looking for a better solution